# Consider the diagonals of a 21-gon. Prove that at least one angle of less than 1 degree is formed.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, proof-explanation, angle, polygons

I think it should be solved using the pigeonhole principle. The answer is:

A $21-$gon has $189$ diagonals. If through a point in the plane, we draw parallels to these diagonals, $2 × 189 = 378$ adjacent angles are formed. The angles sum up to $360^\circ$, and thus one of them must be less than $1^\circ$.

I do not understand what is meant by "we draw parallels to these diagonals" nor where $360$ came from. The only solution I could think of was drawing all the diagonals through the same point and then counting how many angles "make up" the full circle of angles; I do not know if this is the correct interpretation.

Comment: Are angles of 0 degrees considered?

Comment: I think you have the correct interpretation. You pick a point $P$, any point in the plane; for each of the $189$ diagonals, you draw a line through $P$, parallel to that diagonal; that cuts a full $360$ around $P$ into $378$ pieces, and so on.

Comment: It raises this question: is there a hexagon where all the angles between diagonals are exactly $20$ degrees?

Comment: As you can see following the answer of Mathlander, what is postulated in your title is erroneous. Is it an exercise that has been given to you or have conceived it ?

Comment: Could you answer my question ?

Answer (score 3):

The reasoning given is correct. By "we draw parallels to these diagonals," it means "we draw the unique line parallel to a given diagonal, for every single diagonal."

However, if $0-$degree angles are not counted as "angles", it is false.

Proof: Every diagonal of a regular $21$-gon is in one of at most $21$ directions which have angles of $8\frac{4}{7}$ degrees with each other. Therefore, the minimum angle in this case is at least $8\frac{4}{7}$ degrees, which is much greater than $1$ degree.

In fact, $8\frac{4}{7}$ degrees is optimal, since all directions of the diagonals that connect a vertex and another vertex $10$ edges away are different (since they either intersect at a vertex or inside the polygon, and therefore cannot be parallel), and $8\frac{4}{7}$ degrees is optimal for $21$ different directions.

Comment: It may not be true that the minimum angle is $60/7$ degrees; what is true is that $60/7$ is the best result you can get from this approach.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is fixed now.

Comment: I confirm the reasoning and the result of mathlander.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I proved that $60/7$ degrees is the minimum angle.

Answer (score 3):

A generalization of the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) states that the measure of a pair of vertical angles made by two chords is equal to *half the sum* of the measures of the two arcs subtended by those angles. (When the chords intersect *on* the circle, one of those arc-measures vanishes and we get the IAT. When extended chords meet *outside* the circle, we take *half the difference* of the arc measures.)

[image]
$$\theta=\frac12(\alpha+\beta)$$

When the endpoints of the chords are vertices of an $n$-gon, then those arc-measures are integer multiples of $360^\circ/n$, so that the angle measure is a non-negative integer multiple of $180^\circ/n$. If the chords are distinct and non-parallel, then the smallest possible measure is $180^\circ/n$ (attained when the chords meet at a common vertex and have adjacent vertices for their "other" endpoints; attained more generally by *extended* chords when the numbers of subtended edges differ by $1$). When $n=21$, this is $60^\circ/7$, which is greater than $1^\circ$.

Comment: This is also a spectacular answer. +1. Where did you find the generalization?

Comment: @mathlander: I learned the generalization back in high school geometry. It's surprisingly elusive on the web, which is part of why I chose to present it here even though your answer handles the question nicely.

Comment: Is there a link which I can visit to see it?

Comment: @mathlander: Try a web search for "angle of intersecting chords" (also secants and/or tangents, for the exterior version).